# Pass secret env variables to Node script using PM2

Tags: node.js, pm2

I'm currently storing my secret env variables in a GPG encrypted file. Before running my script, I run `eval $(gpg -d ./env.gpg)`.

However, with PM2, I can't figure out how to pass the env variables properly. One option is include the secret env variables directly in `ecosystem.json` and then encrypt the whole file. However, I'd prefer to be able to commit `ecosystem.json` to Git.

I did some research and it looks like some people are using a hacky approach of modifying `ecosystem.json` using Git hooks. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Just to note, your secret env variables should not be committed to git. Instead on your server you would set the appropriate values either in the environment before you start pm2 or in your pm2 config file. With this approach you a) remove the need to encrypt your secret values b) gain some flexibility by allowing different values for different environments, e.g. dev vs. prod

Comment: @tantalum this works if you have 1 or two servers. If you have dozens with the env variables changing frequently, it's not a practical way of doing it.